# Team Foundation Server (TFS) tries to connect to server when working offline

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, server, offline

I wanted to work offline because the TFS server is not currently available.  Under the 'Advanced' button (seen in picture below) for one of the Working Folders within my workspace, I selected 'local' (instead of 'server') for the location.  I thought this would allow me to work offline; however, after reading up on working offline, I realize this was not the correct action.

Now, the server is down and I cannot connect to the Source Control Explorer (see figure 2) to tell VS to work offline.  Therefore, VS will randomly (maybe after certain interaction i attempt with VS) try to reconnect to the server.  Additionally, there is no 'File | Source Control | go-offline' option.

QUESTION: is there anyway to tell TFS to stop trying to reconnect to the server (because server is down) after the server is already down (but not delete pending changes for the workspace).

[image]

[image]

Edit: using VS 2013

Comment: I don't know the answer to your specific question, but in case you don't get an answer: Later, when the server is back online, copy all the files to another location, connect back up, set your 'local' workspace and then manually copy the files over. Visual Studio will detect the changes and automatically check out the required files, creating you new pending changes. You must have local workspace for this to work

Comment: Also, update which what version of TFS you are using.

Comment: okay, I'll make sure to make the copy and manually copy files over.  Thanks SA for the tip.

Comment: @Fractal, any further information when and how VS tries to connect to TFS server? Any screenshot or error/log message?

Comment: Not an answer to the question.  TFS will try to connect to the server when you check-out files or try to change the name of a file checked out.  
Another tip is that it is a good idea to not have the TFS Source Control Explorer open when trying to offline ... I believe not having the SCE window open when trying to work offline will help to avoid the problem of TFS trying to reconnect to the server.